# Python - Google Colab Change Directory after wget

Tags: python, directory, fasttext

in Google Colaboratory, I downloaded fasttext module with !wget command.

```
!wget https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/archive/v0.1.0.zip
!unzip v0.1.0.zip
```

It works fine. "fastText-0.1.0" file extracted successfully. After then:

```
!cd fastText-0.1.0
```

I get this error:

/bin/bash: line 0: cd: fastText-0.1.0: No such file or directory

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to unzip the zip file to get this directory! The error message seems obvious.

Comment: You can see the !unzip command.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. Now, how do you know the unzipped directory name is `fastText-0.1.0`. You may need to check you filesystem to check the unziped archive name.